# When I change book name in Calibre I lose the books and get links instead - Why?

Tags: permissions, calibre

When I change a book name in the Edit Metadata screen, Calibre is changing the folder where the books reside. after the change I get a link in the new folder to a file in the old folder. I have 2 issues with this.

1. The original folder is being deleted because the book name has changed. Now any file in the old folder is deleted along with the folder.
2. Since I'm changing the name I want the files to be in the new folder not just a link to the file. (This may be irrelevant since the file is anyways being deleted so I'm losing it).

   Example of the problem.

**Folder tree before name change**

```
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/BookName.epub
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/cover.jpg
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/metadata.opf
```

Changing book name "Original Book Name -> New Book Name"

**Folder tree after name change**

```
The folder Of "Original Book Name" was deleted altogether.

/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/New Book Name/
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/New Book Name/NewBookName.epub -> /data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/.l2s.BookName.epub0001
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/New Book Name/cover.jpg  -> /data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/Original Book Name/.l2s.cover.jpg0001
/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/Calibre Library/Temp Author/New Book Name/metadata.opf
```

I'm using "Termux" terminal on an Android device and running a ubuntu distro with proot. The Calibre library resides on an external sd card that is mounted on `/data/data/termux.com/files/home/ext4-fs/`

I remember once addressing this or a similar problem and solving it with changing permissions on the files. I'm trying this but not being successful.

The following is what I tried.

1. Change the group of the files to 'everybody'
2. Change mode of files to allow group read/wrie/execute
3. Running the proot as root.

None of these seem to help. Can someone please help me with this. I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: Please provide clear OS/product & release details. What do you define as a *ubuntu distro*?

Comment: Ubuntu version 22.10 running with proot on Termux running on Android 10.

Comment: This sounds very much like a Calibre problem. Maybe file an issue with the upstream calibre project?